# Proper way to use latest babel and Jest in a Vue or Quasar CLI project

Tags: npm, jestjs, babeljs, vue-cli-3, quasar-framework

Need to use Babel 7 and Jest together with the Vue/Quasar CLI.

I've been told in the quasar discord chat that Jest needs Babel 7 beta 54.  Jest documentation is lacking and confusing surrounding babel 7 support, so I went with the recommendation in discord and got it working perfectly, but I get lots of warnings during "npm install" now.

When I google for these warnings all I can find is people who created github issues asking for help in the Jest and Babel and Quasar and Vue CLI repos, and people telling them "they're just warnings, not errors" and the issues being closed: Nobody solves or explains the issue.

Can someone please explain how to get Babel 7 and Jest to work with the Quasar/Vue CLI without warnings, or explain why the warning messages are showing?

**NOTE: The warning message texts are actually incorrect.  I have the versions being asked for installed.**

**NOTE: I have tried installing 7.0.0-beta.50 and every version in between, both in devDependencies and dependencies to no avail of the warnings.**

If it helps, I'm using Windows 10, although fellow devs have said they get the same warnings on Macs and Linux.

Warning messages that appear when you type "`npm install`" with the below package.json:

```
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/preset-stage-3@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.0.0-beta.54 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "debug": "^4.1.0",
    "es6-iterator": "^2.0.3",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.3.3",
    "vue-json-pretty": "^1.4.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar-vue2": "^1.2.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/types": "7.1.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.0.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^4.0.9",
    "@storybook/addons": "^4.0.9",
    "@storybook/vue": "^4.0.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.26",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue-a11y": "0.0.28",
    "fse": "^4.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "lighthouse": "^3.0.3",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "quasar-cli": "^0.17.22",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "socket.io-mock": "^1.2.3",
    "strip-ansi": "=3.0.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.1",
    "wallaby-vue-compiler": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 5.6.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 10"
  ]
}
```

Comment: isn't that something that is planned to work in 1.0?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? 1.0 of what? And do you have any other details?

Comment: The blog article over at quasar mentions a new testing library for quasar apps: https://medium.com/quasar-framework/quasar-1-0-sneak-peek-727b4e490899